# How to flatten multilevel index in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to put all columns on the same level as Date, so that the columns are equal to ['Date', 'Symbols', 'Adj Close', 'Close', 'High', 'Low', 'Open', 'Volume'] with 'Date' being also the Index. How can I do that?

```
from pandas_datareader import data
stocks = ['GOOG', 'AAPL','MSFT']
data = data.DataReader(stocks,'yahoo')
data = data.stack(level=1)
data = pd.DataFrame(data.to_records())
data.set_index('Date')
```

Currently when I `print(data.columns)` I see `Index(['Date', 'Symbols', 'Adj Close', 'Close', 'High', 'Low', 'Open','Volume'], dtype='object')` which means there are still 2 levels in this dataframe.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkbfS.png)

Comment: Hi Alexander, please use a code block to post data instead of using an image (and only use images for charts and such info that is not easily transformed to text)... So, you want `Date` to be the Index AND a column? duplicating the same dates?... Can you please elaborate on your intentions? it seems to me you could avoid that step. That said, try creating a new column `data['Date_copy'] = data.Index` after your sample code.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas_datareader as web
stocks = ['GOOG', 'AAPL','MSFT']
data = web.DataReader(stocks,'yahoo')
data = data.stack(level=1)
data = pd.DataFrame(data.to_records())
data.set_index('Date')

data.reindex()
```

Comment: It seems you were looking for `drop=False` parameter of [set_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)